# How to animate from top of the page to bottom of the page when the page loading?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a page height of 1500px. I want to open the page, then show the page from top to the bottom for a review. I think jQuery animate can do that. But how do I do that? I should add a `div content` between body then call the jQuery? And must I add a function like `window.onload`? At least my code can not work.

```
jQuery('#content').stop().animate({bottom: '1500px'},300)
.stop().animate({top: '1500px'},300);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: '+=1500'}, 2000);
});
```

If everything you got is contained by `#content`, you can replace `document.body` with that of course.

Comment: Thanks for help. use `#content` can work well, and `$(document.body)` should be replace to `$('body,html')`, then it can also work well. Good night and Merry Christmas.